# Amount is wrong when transferring ERC-20 token with web3.js

Tags: web3js, erc-20, transfer

When I run the method on Etherscan or Remix, the amount is correct, and it displays with the token's symbol `CSHIP`.

[image]

Yet for the life of me, I can't get the right amount to show up when I am implementing this in my javascript app. My code is below:

```
let amt = 1e16;
const hash = await web3React.library.provider.request({
    method: "eth_sendTransaction",
    params: [
        {
            from: web3React.account,
            to: farmAddress,
            data: shipContract.methods
            .transfer(farmAddress, web3.utils.toHex(amt) + "")
            .encodeABI(),
            nonce: (await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3React.account, "latest")) + "",
        },
    ],
});
```

And here is the result when that code is run:
[image]

Note that not only is the amount wrong, but the token symbol `CSHIP` does not appear. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `to` parameter should be the address of the contract you're executing the transfer method on - the address of the token you are sending. Probably `shipContract.address`.

Comment: If you notice in the screenshots, the recipient address is the same in both metamask popups

Comment: The address you're referring to is to whom are you sending the funds, not which contract are you using to send the funds. You can see that in Remix you're executing the transfer function on the CSHIP contract - address 0x391 - but in JS you're executing it on farmAddress - 0xc17. So my original answer holds: you need to keep the farmAddress inside the transfer, but change the "to" field to the address of CSHIP - probably shipContract.address.

Comment: That's what it was. Thanks for the further explanation!